# On Mac Excel, insert a function in cell B2 to display the current date and time, and then format as a Long Date

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using this formula**
=NOW()**

but, This formula is only showing the date and not the time

**=NOW(), tried this, please can somebody help me with this, i am trying to find from a long time, thank you for help in  advance**

Comment: =NOW() will give you the value for date and time, you just need to format the cell with a date/time format. You can use an existing one (look under Format cells/Number/Time) or a custom one (like `dd-mm-yy hh:mm`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume these would work on Mac as well as PC: `=TEXT(NOW(),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm")` or `=TEXT(NOW(),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm am/pm")`